# Equality ruby vs rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

After reading [this article](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/2.4.0/RSpec/Matchers#eq-instance_method) and [this doc](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/11/17/does-ruby-have-too-many-equality-tests/), I have questions regarding Ruby and RSpec equalities. Is the following assumption correct?

1. Ruby's == is equivalent to RSpec eq
2. Ruby's eql? is equivalent to RSpec eql
3. Ruby's equal? is equivalent to RSpec equal

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers):

```
a.should equal(b) # passes if a.equal?(b)
a.should eql(b)   # passes if a.eql?(b)
a.should == b     # passes if a == b
a.should be(b)    # passes if a.equal?(b)
a.should eq(b)    # passes if a == b
```